# Get Window object in an app that doesn't have an Activity

Tags: android

I have an Android application that consists of a Service and a View only. I don't use any activities.

The View is inflated in the Service onCreate method similar to the code block below.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // The floater layout is on top of everything. It does not have a parent.
    floaterView = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.floaterView, null);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(<set params>);
    windowManager.addView(floaterView, params);
}
```

I want to get a reference to the Window object (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) that is connected to this process, but this is usually done with Activity.getWindow().
Since I don't have/want an Activity in my application, this is not possible. I came across methods like View.getWindowToken and View.getWindowId. Maybe I can use these to get the Window?

My question is: How can I get a reference to the Window/Windows objects that are created in this process?

Comment: you have to give overlay permission to the device so that it can be drawn over the apps

Comment: I have the permission. I can inflate the view without any problems. I just want a reference to the Window object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get `window` from service. If you want to get `width` and `height` such information of the current window you can get it in 
 Display object. You can get it by `windowManager.getDefaultDisplay()`.

From service to add view to the current window use `windowManager.addView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`

To remove view from service use `windowManager.removeViewImmediate(View view)`

To update view from service use `windowManager.updateViewLayout(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`

Before this, you have to get **window overlay permission** to achieve this.

You can get permission by calling this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getActivity().getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_OVERLAY_PICKUP);
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: What I really want to do is to get the Window object in order to dim the window/everything behind my view. I guess I will have to find another way to dim the background if it's impossible to get the Window object, but that's another problem. I just wanted to see if it's possible to get the Window object from a service.

Comment: You can't get window object in service. I said this in very first line.

Comment: Yes and I appreciate your answer. But I want it confirmed before I accept "it can't be done" as an answer. Hope you understand.

Comment: I agree that.we can't get Window object from service.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void viewDialog() {
        try {

            final View Dialogview = View.inflate(getBaseContext(), R.layout.alert_open_internet, null);
            final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
            windowManager.addView(Dialogview, params);

            Button btn_cancel = (Button) Dialogview.findViewById(R.id.btn_canceldialog_internetblocked);
            Button btn_okay = (Button) Dialogview.findViewById(R.id.btn_openmainactivity);
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) Dialogview.findViewById(R.id.rellayout_dialog);
//        windowManager.addView(relativeLayout,params);
            btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                if (Dialogview != null) {
//                                ( (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(Dialogview);
                                    windowManager.removeViewImmediate(Dialogview);
                                    windowManager.removeView(Dialogview);
                                }
                            } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                // Handle or log or ignore
                            } catch (final Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                // Handle or log or ignore
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    if (windowManager != null && Dialogview != null) {
//                                    ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(Dialogview);
                                        windowManager.removeViewImmediate(Dialogview);
                                        windowManager.removeView(Dialogview);
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            //    ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(Dialogview);
//                        windowManager.removeView(Dialogview);


                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            btn_okay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //        ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).removeView(Dialogview);
                            try {
                                if (windowManager != null && Dialogview != null) {
                                    windowManager.removeView(Dialogview);
                                }
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SplashActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                windowManager.removeViewImmediate(Dialogview);
                                windowManager.removeView(Dialogview);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //` windowManager.removeView(Dialogview);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

calll above method in handler in service otherwise it will lead to crash

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        viewDialog();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my question. I want a reference to the Window object, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add views to the window manager and dim behind the window by adding the dim flag and amount to the WindowManager object, like this:

```
val wm: WindowManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager 
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_view, null, false) as ViewGroup
val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )


params.dimAmount = 0.5f
wm.addView(view, params)
```

This also works for blurs on Android 12 if the device supports it.
For that you should add the flag

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND
```

and set the blur amount

```
params.blurBehindRadius = 20
```